# Python convert Python string to Numpy unicode string

Tags: python, string, numpy

I cannot work out how to convert a Python string to a numpy unicode string

```
import numpy as np

py_str = "hello world"
#numpy_str = ?
```

Comment: What is a numpy unicode string?  Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Why not `np.array(py_str)`?  In Py3 that will be uncode.  Or `np.unicode_(py_str)`.  Generally a single element array is more useful, though they share many of the same attributes and methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert a Python string to a numpy string you can simply use the numpy constructor.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> py_str = "hello world"
>>> numpy_str = np.string_(py_str)
>>> type(numpy_str)
<type 'numpy.string_'>
```

**EDIT:**

Following @hpaulj suggestion you may find that the `dtype` of `numpy_str` is string88 not unicode. Next, I add the code to convert it to unicode with the content, type, and dtype checks.

```
>>> numpy_str
'hello world'
>>> type(numpy_str)
<type 'numpy.string_'>
>>> numpy_str.dtype.name
'string88'

>>> numpy_unicode = numpy_str.astype(unicode)

>>> numpy_unicode
u'hello world'
>>> type(numpy_unicode)
<type 'numpy.unicode_'>
>>> numpy_unicode.dtype.name
'unicode352'
```

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks. I updated the answer following your suggestion.